# I want to remove a <tr> that contains a certain <td> value from a certain j Query selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a table with some tr tags and td inside them.I want to remove the row that contains a certain value from element which has text inside equal to p tag text.

I've Tried this but not solved my problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user").alert();
  $('td:first-child').parent('tr:not($('#user ').text())').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="user">some user.........</p>
<table class="entries">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>user</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="entries">test</td>
      <td class="entries">user1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="entries">test</td>
      <td class="entries">user2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ayush Best not to correct typos in a post's code, since that is often part of the problem - prompt the poster to fix it instead

Comment: Ah right ok, rolled back.

Comment: the best way is to use for loop and check each value of the td tags with your desired value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the point .. You can use `.filter()` then compare the text

The Next example comparing the **exact text** between `td` text and `p` text

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var P_Text = $('#user').text();  // get p text
  $('td').filter(function(){       // filter tds
    return $(this).text() === P_Text; // if this td text is equal the exact text of the p text
  }).closest('tr').remove();       // go to closest row then remove it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="user">user1</p>
<table class="entries">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>user</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="entries">test</td>
      <td class="entries">user1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="entries">test</td>
      <td class="entries">user2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Additional**  You may need

- `.toLowerCase()` check for lower case
- `.trim()` to avoid any white spaces
- `.indexOf()` returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string .. `return $(this).text().indexOf(P_text) > -1`

Comment: You're welcome @GiorgosGeorgantas .. Have a nice day :-)